# App\Todo::lead must return a relationship instance, but "null" was returned. Was the "return" keyword used?

Tags: php, html, eloquent, laravel-7

I have Todo and Tbl_leads model and there corresponding tables todos and tbl_leads. When I am trying todo have the lead name it throw me an error.

```
#This is Tbl_leads model
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tbl_leads extends Model
{

    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'tbl_leads';
    //Primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'ld_id';
    //Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'ld_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
    ];

    public function tasks() {
        $this->hasMany('App\Todo', 'lead_id','ld_id');
    }
}
```

This is Todo Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Todo extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [

        'title',
        'description',
        'user_id',
        'outcome_id',
        'lead_id',
        'tasktype_id',
        'due_time',
        'complete_time',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'due_time' => 'datetime',
        'complete_time',
    ];

    public function lead() {

        $this->belongsTo('App\Tbl_leads', 'lead_id');
    }
}
```

This is my index method

```
 public function index()
    {
        $tasks = Todo::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('taskmanagement.cruds.index',compact('tasks'));
    }
```

this is blade where I want get the the first name from Tbl_leads model

```
div class="card-body">
  <ul class="todo-list" data-widget="todo-list">
  @forelse($tasks as $task)
   <div class="col-3">
    @if(!empty($task->lead_id))
              <div>
             <small>Related to</small>
</div>
                                        <div class="mt-0">
          <a href="#">
<strong class="mx-4">{{$task->lead->first_name}}</strong>
</a> 
</div>
 @endif
   </div>                                   
      </div>
      </div>
       </li>
   @empty
     <p class="text-center">No Tasks is available</p>
   @endforelse
```

Plz can anyone tells me what I have done wrong. And I know the model name and there primary key slightly different is not set accordingly to laravel. Is my model relationship correct?

Comment: You forgot the `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let me clarify few points to you. Firstly you need to put a `return` in each relationship. For example:

```
public function lead() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tbl_leads', 'lead_id');
}
```

> Next thing you are showing this portion `{{$task->lead->first_name}}` which is called lazy loading. It means if you are displaying `100` records of `Todo` then you are querying database `101` times. `1` for `Todo` and `100` times for `lead->first_name`. Which is not good. So what you can do in your `index` method pass your relation in `with()` so that it will be eager loaded. Means it will become just one or two query or simply a join. So it will be fast. Example of your `index` method...

```
public function index()
{
    $tasks = Todo::with('lead')->latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('taskmanagement.cruds.index',compact('tasks'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you I forget about return. And thanks for tips eager load. I will keep in mind this method.